# WPF Style override Height

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-properties, wpf-style

I have an element from third party library in my xaml file

```
<core:CheckBox />
```

It has its style in that library

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type controls:CheckBox}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:CheckBox}">
    <Style.Setters>
      <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="170" />
      <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="60" />
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:CheckBox}">
            <controls:Button x:Name="Button" 
              Width="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Width}" 
              Height="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Height}"
              ...
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      ...
</Style>
```

Unfortunatelly as the Height and Width are set, it does not want to stretch.

I cannot modify the Style, which is in the third-party library. Situation has its pros, because if they change the Style, my element will have an unified look with rest of the system.

I would like to use the Style, but somehow drop Height and Width setters. 
Any ideas?

Edit:
CheckBox is in a Grid and it does not fill the cell, that is the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own default style based on third-party default style and reset properties there. I found a way to do it using a value converter:

```
public class DummyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
        // return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

This converter does nothing and doesn't provide value for binding.

```
<local:DummyConverter x:Key="Resetter"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:CheckBox}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:CheckBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Height" 
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource Resetter}}"/>                    
    <Setter Property="Width" 
            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource Resetter}}"/>
</Style>
```

Width and Height are not set intentionally

Comment: Thanks for help. I added more info. CheckBox is in a Grid and it still does not fill the cell.

Comment: @Dela, wpf checkbox is usually a small square. it if has to fill large rectangular area - then it needs `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` or even a new Template, I think

Comment: It has a Template, and it is actually a Button, I will add this to the question too

Answer (score 1):

Answer was in a comment of ASh

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type controls:CheckBox}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:CheckBox}">
    <Style.Setters>
      <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="170" />
      <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="60" />
      <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:CheckBox}">
            <controls:Button x:Name="Button" 
              Width="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Width}" 
              Height="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.Height}"
              <!-- ADDED ALIGNMENT -->
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              ...
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      ...
</Style>
```